# ASP.Net 4.6 + IIS 8.5? How do I add an application?

Tags: asp.net, iis-8.5, dnx

I have a ASP.Net 4.6 application that I want to run on an IIS 8.5 server (Windows Server 2012). Well, I added a new website and selected the "wwwroot/" folder from the "output/" directory. The basic resources seem to work since there is a index.html in that folder. However none of the actual code seems to work.

I am using `dnu publish` to deploy the application.

It creates to folder "approot/" and "wwwroot/" - the wwwroot contains a bin folder with one single "aspnet.loader.ddl" in it.

I probably didn't configure the IIS right, but as said, I been looking for the past week to get a solution and there is almost zero documentation other than "it should work" - well it doesn't.

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it figured out after reading through the GitHub issues:

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/452

For those who have the same issue, you need to deploy with

```
dnu --runtime active
```

Otherwise the DNX runtimes will be not copied. Also you might activated 32bit pools.

All kudos goes to GuardRex.